# How do I transition objects individually?

Tags: editing

How do I do this? the way the objects appear is just so cool

Video:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a 3d animation package and animate the surface textures of the objects. That's how I've done similar effects, and I'd be willing to bet that's how the makers of that clip did it, even though it doesn't look like 3D animation.

You can use Non-Photo-Real (or NPR) rendering to get the anime look. "Toon shading" is what it used to be called, haven't kept up with the current nomenclature, but if you search for ["toon shade blender"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=toon%20shade%20blender&t=ffab&atb=v53-6&ia=web) you should get enough to get you started. Blender is a free 3D animation package.

Comment: Finally, thanks a lot man, I had always been wondering about the cool scenes where the camera started moving in 3d. I just assumed that japanese drew those scenes frame by frame because they're always known for their hardworking attitude. Anyway thanks a lot these cleared up a lot of things.

Comment: There's a lot more 3D animation in anime than you'd expect. It's still hard work, but it's a lot quicker which = cheaper.

Comment: has there been cases where the anime character is 3d.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 ways:

1. Film all the objects separately with green screens. Apply a keyer to each one to key out the green areas, place them all on the timeline, and fade each one in as you see fit.
2. Film them all together, and then manually mask out each object by hand. If the objects are basic shapes it might not be too hard, but if it includes people moving, etc., it could be tough. Then fade the masks out as you see fit.

Comment: how about the colorful...y'know colorful "lines or shapes"

Comment: I would use a motion graphics application like Apple Motion or Adobe After Effects to make those. You generally put the playhead where you want them to start, draw them, and then set the out point just like with an editor. You could also import drawings from Adobe Illustrator or Photoshop.